# Property 'text' does not exist on type 'any[]' - Angular4

Tags: arrays, angular, text, service

I am getting an error at data.text() like below. Am I missing some library? Can anyone provide any advice on this. Thanks

> Property 'text' does not exist on type 'any[]'.'

**service.ts**

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/sml');
        headers.set('Accept', 'text/xml');
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

 getData(): Observable<any> {
         return this.http.get<any>(this.urlNorth, { headers })
                .do(data => {
                    data.text().replace('<string xmlns="http://tmmc.regional/pcms/webservice">', '').replace('</string>', '').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
                    parseString(data, (err, res) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return console.dir('invalid XML');
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(res);
                        }
                    })

                })
```

**component.ts**

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any ;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private _appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { this.getData(); }

  getData(): void {
    this._appService.getData()
      .subscribe(
      (data: any) => this.data = data,
      (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to use in index on data to access items. Its an array. For example `data[0].text()`

Comment: What I am trying to do is to get a set of data from web-service which returns XML then I have to parse them in order to correctly get XML format. parseString converts XML format into object that I can access.. So I thought data.text() will return all of my data?

Comment: The text method doesnt exist on your interface any[]. If you are using the new httpClient you can pass in `responseType: 'text'` to your http.get options to parse the response (https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data) In which case you don't need the `text()` method.

Comment: What do you mean by that I don't need text() method?

Comment: Are you using the new httpClient (from @angular/common/http) or the old http (from @angular/http)? The new httpClient does the parsing within the get method, so no need for `.json()`, `.text()`, etc.

Comment: I am using new httpClient. Problem is that I get the data with responseType: 'text', but it contains some HTML element like &lt and&gt. That's where I am trying to apply text().replace with < and > to make it proper XML  then parseString .

Comment: and i had to get rid of <any> in http.get then I could set responseType..

Comment: What is is the text method on `data.text().replace`. should it not just be `data.replace()` <- At this point the get has parsed your response for you

Comment: It is working with `<any>`? What is the problem?

Comment: If I include <any>, it gives an error like :  'Error'
message: 'Argument of type '{ responseType: "text"; headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; respons...'.Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.'  So I can't set responseType header

Comment: @K.Son There is some discussion on this issue (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any type (`<any []>`) in your http-request:

In your service:

`return this.http.get(this.urlNorth, { headers })` // removed type.

and your component

`(data: any) => this.data = data,` // removed []

I added a working example here using the same method as you are, but with different data:

https://plnkr.co/edit/29MyR2oPAHtE883AUlFY?p=preview

I am using `map` instead of `do`, but that is because I was not able to get the do-operator to work in plunkr. It should work with both.

I made a method in the component (better to do it in a service as you do):

```
   getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('test.html', {})
      .map(data => return data.text(););
  }
```

and then inside the constructor:

```
 this.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log("data",data);
      this.data = data;
    });
```

Comment: please refer to updated code. Did you mean like this?

Comment: Yes, your updated code looks correct. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: I don't get the error, but it returns this error : Server returned code: 200, error message is: Http failure during parsing for my service

Comment: I updated my answer. Try to remove `<any>` from your service. Just `http.get()`

Comment: I removed all <any> and observable in service. It throws back typerror again in text()

Comment: How does your headers look like? Maybe you don't need any headers

Comment: I tried without headers, not working. I updated my headers.